# UICollectionView and UICollectionViewLayout relationship?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm confused as to how these two classes communicate with each other because I don't see them subclassing one or the other. How does UICollectionViewLayout communicate its information to a UICollectionView exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UICollectionView` has a strong reference to its layout, through its `collectionViewLayout` property.

A `UICollectionViewLayout` has an unretained reference to its collection view, through its `collectionView` property. When you set the collection view's layout, the collection view sets the layout's `collectionView` property back to the collection view.

Most communication between the two objects happens by the collection view sending messages to the layout and receive return values back from those messages. Many of the messages are publicly declared in the `UICollectionViewLayout` class, and you can implement your own layout by making a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` and implementing/overriding methods to respond to those messages.

Comment: So if I subclass UICollectionViewLayout, writing my custom implementations, collection view will refer to that subclass of collection layout instead of its superclass?

Comment: It will, if you create an instance of your layout class and use it when creating the collection view, or later assign it to the collection view's `collectionViewLayout` property. If you're creating the collection view in a storyboard, you can set the layout class in the storyboard.